# A compact infinite topological group with only two closed subgroups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

It can be proved every compact infinite abelian topological group $(A,\tau )$, with $\tau$ nontrivial, has at least three distinct closed subgroups.

Is there any compact infinite non-abelian topological group $(G,\mathcal T)$, with $\mathcal T$ nontrivial, which has only two closed subgroups?

Comment: Do you mean two closed proper subgroups, or one of the two closed subgroups could be $G$? Moreover: given a non abelian compact topological group, there is a characteristic subgroup which is surely closed, proper and abelian. This is the closure of the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Two of the three closed subgroup are $\{1\}$ and $G$. The closure of $\{1\}$ may or may not be the third.

Comment: The closure of $\{ 1\}$ is always a closed subgroup, and moreover it is normal and abelian.

Comment: But may be equal to $\{1\}$ or $G$.

Comment: If it is $G$, then the topology is trivial, and this is not the case. And the same holds for the center $Z(G)$.

Comment: So only the Hausdorff case remains.

Comment: Yes. In my opinion the answer is no, but this is just taste. Actually I have no deeper ideas, since I don't know many non-abelian compact topological groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the group is Hasdorff: otherwise consider the factor group with respect to the closure of $\{ 1\}$. Closed subgroups of the quotient will correspond to closed subgroups of the initial group.

Let $G$ be a non-abelian Hausdorff topological group. Then for all $g \in G$
$$C_G(g) = \{ x \in G : xg=gx\}$$
is a closed subgroup of $G$.

In particular, since $G$ is not abelian, there exist $g,h \in G$ such that $gh \neq hg$. So, $C_G(g)$ and $C_G(h)$ are two distinct closed  non-trivial proper subgroups of $G$ (since $g \in C_G(g) \setminus C_G(h)$ and $h \in C_G(h) \setminus C_G(g)$).

So, it seems that $G$ has at least 4 closed subgroups.

Comment: nothing to do with compactness.

Answer (score 1):

Every infinite locally compact group $G$ has infinitely many closed subgroups.

(1) $G$ is not torsion. Hence, we can suppose that $G$ has a dense, infinite cyclic subgroup $C$. If $G$ is discrete then $G=C$ all subgroups of $C$ are closed, there are infinitely many. Otherwise $G$ is compact. Its Pontryagin dual is discrete infinite, and hence has infinitely many subgroups, which by duality provides as many closed subgroups in $G$.

(2) $G$ is torsion. Since $G$ is infinite and union of its cyclic subgroups, which are all finite, it has infinitely many finite cyclic subgroups, which are closed.

---

I'm not sure whether the result (that there are infinitely many closed subgroups) holds, say, for Polish groups. The above shows that it's enough to assume that $G$ is abelian with a dense infinite cyclic subgroup. In addition, by a dévissage argument, we can assume that the only closed subgroups of $G$ are $\{0\}$ and $G$.

Assuming only Hausdorff, there exists an infinite Hausdorff topological group $G$ with only closed subgroups $\{0\}$ and $G$. Namely, take any dense cyclic subgroup $\langle c\rangle$ of the circle group, with the induced topology. Being cyclic, its nontrivial subgroups all have the form $\langle c^n\rangle$ for some $n\ge 1$, but all these are dense.